# How can I drain a vector in chunks?

Tags: rust

I would like to have something like:

```
fn drain_in_chunks<T>(mut v: Vec<T> {
for chunk in v.drain.chunks(2){
                do_something(chunk)}
}
```

where I remove chunks of size two from `v` in each iteration. Why I want to do this is, because I want to move the chunks into a function. However, I can't move elements from a vector without removing them.

I could do this, but it feels to verbose.

```
for (i, chunk) in v.chunks(2).enumerate().zip(0..) {
    v.drain(i*2..(i+1)*2);
    do_something(chunk)
}
```

Any more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools`'s [`tuples()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuples):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn drain_in_chunks<T>(mut v: Vec<T>) {
    for (a, b) in v.drain(..).tuples() {
        do_something([a, b]);
    }
}
```